# Run MS Unit Tests at Command Prompt By Trait

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, mstest

In Visual Studio 2013, I like to run tests from Test Explorer by Trait as shown in the image below:

[image]

I'm now running these tests from a Visual Studio 2013 command prompt but only want to run for a specific trait and not sure how to do this. I can run all tests in a project with this command:

```
 C:\Directory>MSTEST /testcontainer:Project.dll
```

but haven't been able to find a command to run by a specific trait only. Can anyone help with that command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traits represent the test category and you can filter that by using the `/category:[test category filter]` option

for example, assume I have a test method with the following `TestCategory` attribute

```cs
[TestCategory("IntegrationTest")]
```

To filter on that category the command would look like this

```
C:\Directory>MSTEST /testcontainer:Project.dll /category:IntegrationTest
```

Reference [MSTest.exe command-line options : category](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx#category)